# iOS 10 icloud calendars not showing up (gone after upgrade)

Tags: icloud, calendar, ios

After upgrading my iPhone 5 from iOS 9 directly to iOS 10.0.1, all my icloud calendars are gone.

They don't show up in the `calendars` list in the Calendar app, and dragging said list down to force syncing of the calendars doesn't even show the usual spinning loading bar indicator – the whole iCloud section is just missing from the list. Rebooting didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following finally fixed the issue for me:

1. Sign out of iCloud (Settings -> iCloud -> Sign Out)
2. choosing "delete all iCloud data from iPhone"
3. sign in again
4. wait a couple of minutes

Comment: No dice for me - had no effect.

Answer (score -1):

If you are missing past events, try this: go to Settings>Calendar>Sync. After an iOS upgrade, it defaulted to Events 2 weeks Back, which is why you may not see other older events. You can change it to 1, 3, 6 months back, or All Events.
That restored my missing older events.